# syntax error, unexpected '}' in Anchor Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

My Anchor Tag is like below

```
<a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
```

I tried to change it to Laravel like below

```
{{ HTML::link("{{ route('login') }}", 'log in')}}
```

It says `syntax error, unexpected '}'`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the result of the function `route` directly as a parameter of `link`:

```
{{ HTML::link(route('login'), 'log in') }}
```